# Creating an --all argument

Tags: python, argparse

I am creating a python script that parses log files in XML-format into a SQLite database file. There are several different types of log files, and by default the script only processes the `process-*.xml` files in the given folder. Using `argparser` options the user can control which log files should be included.

```
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process log files into a SQLite database.")
argparser.add_argument("--control", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=False, help="parse control-*.xml into the database")
argparser.add_argument("--dream", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=False, help="parse dream-*.xml into the database")
argparser.add_argument("--error", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=False, help="parse error-*.xml into the database")
argparser.add_argument("--lis", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=False, help="parse lis-*.xml into the database")
argparser.add_argument("--pass", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=False, help="parse pass-*.xml into the database", dest="pass_xml")  # The default .pass not valid attribute
argparser.add_argument("--process", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=True, help="parse process-*.xml into the database")
argparser.add_argument("--uif", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=False, help="parse uif-*.xml into the database")
```

There are also some additional parameters not concerning this that I didn't include here for readability.

I would like to add an `--all` argument that sets all of the above arguments to `True`. Even better would be if e.g. `--all --no-control` would set all arguments to `True` except `control` that would be left as `False`. How can this be acomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about  the simple and obvious solution?

```
argparser.add_argument("--all", action=argparse.store_true, default=False, help="All of the above")

...

if args.all:
    args.control = True
    args.dream = True
    args.error = True
    ...
```

*Addition:*

To get `--all --no-foo` to work remove `default=False` from the `.add_argument`s, which then would set the value to `None` if not specified and `False` if `--no-foo` if specified. Then use

```
if args.all:
    if args.foo == None: args.foo = True
    if args.bar == None: args.bar = True
    ...
```

This way the arguments will be set to `True` only if not explicitly set to `False` using the `--no-foo` option.